# Spring Webflux detects SSE connection cancellation with delay

Tags: netty, spring-webflux, server-sent-events, spring-reactor

I want to use Spring Webflux with Server Sent Events and Netty. I was able to receive events on the client side. But when there are many events one by one and the client cancels the subscription, then the server sends more events and the client does not receive them.

Сhronology:

```
0 - Server checks if the downstream cancelled. It is not cancelled and the server sends event A 
1 - Client receives event A
3 - Client closes SSE connection 
4 - Server checks if the downstream cancelled. It is actually cancelled, but server does not detect it and sends event B 
5 - Server checks if the downstream cancelled. It is actually cancelled, and server detects it and does not send event C
```

The problem here I cannot be sure event B was delivered or not, because at the moment the message sent there is no evidence of closed connection.
So, the question is how can I avoid such situation? How can I know if a message was delivered or connection is  actually open at the moment when the message is sent?

This is my controller:

```
 @GetMapping
  public Flux<ServerSentEvent> stream()  { 
    return Flux.<ServerSentEvent>push(emitter -> {
      long counter = 0;
      while (!emitter.isCancelled()) {
        emitter.next(ServerSentEvent.builder(++counter).build());
        System.out.println(counter);
       }
    }, OverflowStrategy.ERROR);
  }
```

This is a tail of client's log:

```
...

data:212

data:213

data:214
```

This is a tail of server's log:

```
...
213
214
215
216
```

Comment: have you tried using the `isTerminated` instead of `isCancelled`. `ServerSentEvents` is a one way push protocol, there are no acknowledgements (ack's) built into the protocol. So you will never know if the event was received or not.

Comment: `Flux.push` method receive parameter `Consumer<FluxSink>`, and there is no method `isTerminated` in `FluxSink`. 
I guessed that there is no way to know message delivered or not, but decided to ask.  Thank you.